# Is it possible to override minified JavaScript functions

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

Is it possible to override functions contained in a minified Javascript file?

Details:
I'm attempting to override the process() function within the Twitter Boootstrap Typeahead plugin (v2.3.2) in order to add an indicator at the bottom of the drop-down if items returned exceed the items displayed.

Here is my code:

```
var customProcess = function (items) {
    var that = this

    items = $.grep(items, function (item) {
        return that.matcher(item)
    })

    items = this.sorter(items)

    if (!items.length) {
        return this.shown ? this.hide() : this
    }

    //Get the default item slice and determine whether the indicator is needed
    var itemSlice = items.slice(0, this.options.items);
    if (items.length > this.options.items) {
        itemSlice.push("...");
    }

    return this.render(itemSlice).show();
};

// Reassign the typeahead.process() function to the customized
// version that adds a visual indicator if more items are 
// returned than the amount shown (options.items).
$.fn.typeahead.Constructor.prototype.process = customProcess;
```

If I'm using the minified version of the Bootstrap JavaScript (bootstrap.min.js) this fails and actually kills the typeahead functionality completely.  If I instead source the non-minified version (bootstrap.js), it works perfectly.

[As a side note, I previously used the same approach with an older version of the typeahead plugin (v1.8.x I believe) and it worked perfectly with the minimized version as well.  Did I just get lucky?]

Comment: Try minifying the non-minified version (which works for you) using minifiers like http://jscompress.com/ and check if that works.

Comment: @ParthikGosar [jscompress.com](http://www.jscompress.com) was not working, but I found another at [refresh-sf.com/yui](http://refresh-sf.com/yui/).  Using the newly minified file, the override was successful.  As to my original question, it would seem that overriding minified JS is perfectly valid as long as the minified JS is correct.  Am I right?  Thanks for your help!

Comment: yes you are right...one of the common errors while minifying JS files are some times we miss adding semicolons in our code. So when the file is minified, consecutive lines get counted as same line(since there is no semicolon between these lines). Some minifiers add semicolons where necessary, some don't. Such cases introduce errors into the minified files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minification does not change the "visible" API. If you can call a function as library.functionName(...) on the minified library, then you can override that property and turn it into something else (note that a function is just a property called with the execution operator () added to it).

With one caveat: if that function was set up using `Object.defineProperty`, with either default `configurable` and/or `writable` configuration options (or these values explicitly set to `false`), then it will be "locked" from being modified (it will not be deletable and/or assignable, respectively).

Comment: @Kamerman Thanks for taking the time to provide an answer.  My issue was solved prior, but your answer matches the question so I'll go ahead and accept it as correct.